# Easiest way to place time variable to smalldatetime variable (only time part keeping the date)

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2008, time

I have two variables

```
declare @dt1 smalldatetime = '2020-07-30 10:00:00'
declare @t1 time = '13:00:00'
```

What is the easiest way to put `t1` to `dt1` to get `'2020-07-30 13:00:00'` (without loosing 2020-07-30)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would `cast()` the `smalldatetime` to a `date` to truncate the time component, then back to `smalldatetime`. Then you can just `cast()` to other time component to a `smalldatetime` as well, and add both:

```
select 
    cast(cast(@dt1 as date) as smalldatetime) 
    + cast(@t1 as smalldatetime) as newdatetime
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4d792d36607f978edfdea21e202813b9)**:

```
| newdatetime      |
| :--------------- |
| 2020-07-30 13:00 |
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@dt1,DATEPART(hour,@dt1),DATEPART(hour,@t1)),DATEPART(MINUTE,@dt1),DATEPART(MINUTE,@t1)),DATEPART(SECOND,@dt1),DATEPART(SECOND,@t1))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would, personally, convert them to ISO `varchar` values, concatenate, and convert back:

```sql
DECLARE @dt1 smalldatetime = '2020-07-30T10:00:00';
DECLARE @t1 time = '13:00:00';

SELECT CONVERT(smalldatetime,CONVERT(varchar(10),@dt1,126) + 'T' + CONVERT(varchar(8),@t1,114),126);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
declare @dt1 smalldatetime = '2020-07-30 10:00:00'
declare @t1 time = '13:00:00'


SELECT CAST(LEFT(CONCAT(CAST(@dt1 AS DATE), 'T', @t1), 19) AS SMALLDATETIME)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either add three hours to the current `SMALLDATETIME` or create a new one by concatenating the desired parts:

```sql
DECLARE @dt1 SMALLDATETIME = '2020-07-30 10:00:00'
DECLARE @t1 TIME = '13:00:00'

SELECT
    @dt1 AS "source",
    DATEADD(HOUR, 3, @dt1) AS "three hours added",  -- just add three hours
    CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME,  -- concatenate the desired parts and convert
        DATETIMEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(YEAR, @dt1),
                        DATEPART(MONTH, @dt1),
                        DATEPART(DAY, @dt1),
                        DATEPART(HOUR, @t1),
                        DATEPART(MINUTE, @t1),
                        DATEPART(SECOND, @t1),
                        0)
    ) AS "concatenated parts"
```

Results:

```
source              |three hours added      |concatenated parts
----------------------------------------------------------------
2020-07-30 10:00:00 |2020-07-30 13:00:00    |2020-07-30 13:00:00
```